# subscribe handler in ObservableArray cannot access parent/root

Tags: knockout.js

I have a ko.observableArray and I've added a subscriber for items in the observable array:
`eventDate.subscribe(function(newDate) { ... }`

Within that handler, I have no access to the parent or root of my view model.

When I access `this`, I get a reference to `window`.  What I would like to do is get access to the scope which contains the observable array. (I have tried normal and fat arrow `=>` in coffeescript for scope).

My reasoning is that I have data that I didn't want duplicated/referenced within the observable array for each item.  I mostly have experience with backbone, so perhaps this is not the "knockout.js" way.

My goal is to have `ko.applyBindings new MainModel()` instead of adding a reference for my model in `window`.

I've created a jsfiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/brianzinn/r4bd8/

Thanks.  Does anybody know a solution?

## Edit

Passing the view model in the constructor gives access to the parent, is this a good practice?
http://jsfiddle.net/brianzinn/r4bd8/7/

Comment: I was halfway through telling you to pass the parent in from the constructor until I decided to read your whole question. That's what I would do.

Comment: I decided to post my answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is pass the parent down through the `Row` constructor. Then you will have easy access to the Row's parent.

It would look something like:

```
class Row
    constructor: (parent) ->
    ...
```

Then you can access `parent` from within the `Row`.

Constructing the Row would change slightly too:

```
@rows = ko.observableArray [new Row(this)]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Passing the view model in the constructor gives access to the parent, is this a good practice?

Just pass `allSports` array in `Row` constructor.
Also as I see you don't change list of sports, so it would be better if you'll make `allSports` a constant instead of `ko.observableArray`.

Comment: Thank for your reply.  allSports changes in my real-world example, but thanks for the tip.  Gave answer to jjnguy as he was first.